# Реализация Reader-Writer мьютекса

Tags: многопоточность, sdl

Использую библиотеку SDL2, там есть только обычные мьютексы, хочется получить reader-writer мьютексы. Какие есть эффективные способы их реализации?

Reader-Writer мьютекс можно захватить на запись и на чтение. Читать могут сколько угодно потоков, записывать - только один (одновременно читать и писать тоже нельзя).

Comment: возьмите pthread_rwlock

Comment: Это кроссплатформенное решение?

Comment: pthread поддерживается на  FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Linux, Mac OS X , Solaris, iOS, Android (NDK)..
Для Windows есть порт pthread-w32.